# c/c++ using else instead of if not

Tags: c++, c

Encountered a bit of weird-looking code and it got me wondering if there's any practical application to it, or if it's just a random oddity.

The code essentially looks like this:

```
#ifdef PREPROCESSOR_CONDITION
    if (runtime_condition) {
    } else
#endif
    {
        //expression
    }
```

I included the macro bit, though I doubt it has any bearing. There's no code that runs when runtime_condition is true, only the else block. I figure this ought to be completely identical to using if(!runtime_condition) and no else block (which would have been more straightforward), but maybe there's some kind of compiler-optimizey thing happening?

Or, you know, it could be that there used to be something in the if block that got deleted and nobody bothered to change the expression.

Comment: With `if (runtime_condition)` and empty code blocks, it is an example waiting for someone to "fill in the blanks". It is not an oddity, but well used technique.

Comment: Is this code fragment publicly available? We might be able to give a better answer if we knew the context. Sometimes it's clearer not to add a negation to an already-complicated `if` condition. A coworker used to add the comment `/* how nice */` in the empty true part to show readers that it wasn't an oversight.

Comment: If it's checked into some kind of version control system, you could check the file history to see if code was removed from the empty block. With git you could use `git blame` for example.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I wouldn't say the context regarding the condition is all that complicated. It's from the Qt framework, qdockarealayout.cpp [link](https://github.com/openwebos/qt/blob/master/src/gui/widgets/qdockarealayout.cpp) on this version line 1040

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "macro bit" is significant.

Consider what happens if the programmer mistakenly changes the snippet to

```
#ifdef PREPROCESSOR_CONDITION
if (runtime_condition)
{
}
else
#endif
{
    //expression
}
else
{
    // another expression
}
```

This will result in a compilation error, regardless of whether `PREPROCESSOR_CONDITION` is defined or not.

With your change, viz;

```
#ifdef PREPROCESSOR_CONDITION
if (!runtime_condition)
#endif
{
    //expression
}
else
{
    // another expression
}
```

it will compile if `PREPROCESSOR_CONDITION` is defined, but fail if it is not defined.

If the programmer who adds the `else` only attempts compilation in conditions with `PREPROCESSOR_CONDITION` defined, no problem will be found.   There will then be a latent defect in the code, that will not be exposed until the code is compiled with `PREPROCESSOR_CONDITION` undefined.

This may seem minor in a single code snippet, but compilation errors occurring by surprise (e.g. code breaking in unexpected places) is a significant productivity concern if it occurs in larger projects.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, it's a pretty large project with a lot of target platforms so there are quite a lot of these preprocessor conditions used to manage features. Funny, I've just found an instance later in the file that does the same thing "my" way. Yeesh.

Comment: That instance is an example of a latent defect waiting to be found by some poor developer in that project.    Personally, I'd submit a bug report - particularly if there is a coding guideline in play which requires dealing with this sort of thing (then all you need to do is cite deviation from the guideline/policy).

Answer (score 2):

Ensuring the conditional definitely *always* has two branches (on those occasions when it is compiled as a conditional) guarantees that someone who works on a platform that always has `PREPROCESSOR_CONDITION` defined won't absent-mindedly add a real `else` block below, which clearly isn't how this block is supposed to work (or worse, "fix" it so that their code *does* compile everywhere, but in the process damage whatever the intent of the original author was in constructing their blocks that way).

If that is the intent, it would normally make sense to communicate it explicitly by hiding the exact details of the `if-empty-else` behind a macro named something like `UNLESS`, though.

---

It definitely isn't anything to do with optimization. If you think in terms of the jumps involved, a compiler already has to invert the value of the predicate to decide whether to skip the block or not (i.e. `if (A) {B;} C:...` really means `if (!A) goto C; B; C:...`), which means it folds the hand-written `!` at the outermost level of the expression into the conditional's structure anyway; since most instruction sets will provide both *jump-if-true* and *jump-if-not-true* instructions, doing this is completely free, and both ways to write "if not" in the source will produce the same machine code on even a very simple compiler without any optimization.